# How to declare type of multiple variables in same line

Tags: haskell

Suppose my Haskell file contains following declarations.

```
a :: Integer
b :: Double
c :: String

a = 10
b = 12.34
c = "Abcd"
```

I am able to assign values to variables in same line like below.

```
 (a, b, c) = (10, 12.34, "Abcd")
```

My question is, how can I define the type signature in same line?

When I used following statement.

```
  (a, b, c) :: (Integer, Double, String)
```

I am getting following error.

```
Invalid type signature: (a, b, c) :: (Integer, Double, String)
    Should be of form <variable> :: <type>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(a :: Integer, b :: Double, c :: String) = ...`
```

should work, but probably requires the `ScopedTypeVariables` extension.

Answer (score 8):

If you really have to do this, you can:

```
a :: Integer; b :: Double; c :: String
(a, b, c) = (10, 12.34, "Abcd")
```

Though I'd recommend you learn to like multiple lines, since that's generally better style.

Comment: One line declaration is useful when all variables have the same type: `a,b,c,d,e,f :: Int`

Answer (score 2):

If they form a structure (that makes sense as a composite), structuring them first might be an option:

```
vals :: (Integer, Double, String)
vals = (10, 12.34, "Abcd")

(a, b, c) = vals
```

I don't see a reason to not put them on separate lines otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

You can combine the binding and the type declaration in one line.

```
a = 10     :: Int
b = 12.34  :: Double
c = "Abcd" :: String
```

There's not much value in separating the two, since you can't really assign a different value to any of these names later.